# Como colocar uma imagem dentro do echo e não mostrar se for vazia

Tags: php, mysqli

Fiz o código para mostrar apenas se tiver imagem, só que ela mostra também o corpo das vazias, ele diz no código fonte da pagina que meu PHP é um comentário como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra não mostrar as fotos vazias do jeito que está aqui?

```
echo '

                  <php

                  $seleciona = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM postagem where status=1 ORDER BY id desc");
                  while($campo=mysqli_fetch_array($seleciona)){
                    $nome_imagem = $campo["nome_imagem"];                    
                    ?>
                    <center>
                    <div id="panel" align="left">
                    <label class="titulo">&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $result1[$i][1] . '</label><br>
                    <p class="descricao">'. $result1[$i][2] . '</p><br>

                    <?php if ($nome_imagem != null){?><p><img src="foto/'. $result1[$i][3] . '" class="foto"></p><?php } ?>

                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Postado por: '. $result1[$i][6] . ' em '. $result1[$i][4] . ' às '. $result1[$i][5] . '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a href="0_excluir_postagem.php?editaid='. $result1[$i][0] . '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;     
                    </div></center>  

                    <?php }?> 
                    </div>' ; 

                  }
```

Comment: A sintaxe está errada, remova  esse echo ' no inicio, quanto a imagem, utilizar a função is_file()

Comment: Mas ele tá dentro de um FOR: 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result1); $i++) {
  #Codingo
}

Comment: Tenta `$nome_imagem != ""`

Answer (score 2):

Porque você não cria um método de verificação se a imagem é válida:

```
<?php 
function checkImage($img = null, $nome = null)
{
   if ($img != null && $nome != null) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
   
} ?>


<?php if (checkImage($result1[$i][3],$nome_imagem)):?>
    <p><img src="foto/'. $result1[$i][3] . '" class="foto"></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere:

```
<?php if ($nome_imagem != null){?><p><img src="foto/'. $result1[$i][3] . '" class="foto"></p><?php } ?>
```

Para:

```
<?php if (!empty($nome_imagem)) { ?><p><img src="foto/'. $result1[$i][3] . '" class="foto"></p><?php } ?>
```

Não entendi a lógica de testar uma variável (`$nome_imagem`) e exibir outra (`$result1[$i][3]`). Mas tudo bem. Não é o objetivo da pergunta, muito menos da resposta.

Voltando à pergunta, sobre o `empty()`:

Returna `FALSE` caso a variável testada exista e não esteja vazia. Caso contrário, retorna `TRUE`.

`empty()` considera os seguintes casos como **vazio**:

- "" (uma string vazia)
- 0 (0 como um inteiro)
- 0.0 (0 como um ponto flutuante)
- "0" (0 como uma string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (um array vazio)
- $var; (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

> Referência: [PHP - empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Comparar a variável com `null` iria ignorar todos estes outros casos mencionados. (`if ($nome_imagem != null){ //...`).

Comment: O mesmo resultado, ele mostra as que tem fotos e também o espaço das "IMAGENS" que não possuem.

Comment: @AlisonWalker - "*e também o espaço das "IMAGENS" que não possuem*". Isso quer dizer que vc está armazenando **algo** onde não deveria armazenar no banco de dados. Nesse caso, vc deve aprimorar a forma em que armazena esses dados no seu db ou então criar uma função que **entenda certos dados (este algo) como *sem foto***... Se o seu db segue um padrão para quando não tem foto, fica fácil criar essa função. Basta postar (editando a pergunta) esse *algo* que fica armazenado no seu db quando não tem foto.